# Moving a control with keys

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I am trying to make a mini game with w,a,s,d as forward, left, down and right respectively.

The control moves up, left, down and right but only once. If i press the 'W','S','A' or 'D' key twice or thrice the control only moves up once.

This is the code i have currently for moving the control right:

```
private void moveRight(Button button)
    {
        // Gets the current position of the control
        Point relativePoint = button.TransformToAncestor(parentCanvas).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        // Reason for having relative - relative is that its adding onto the previous point.
        Canvas.SetLeft(button, relativePoint.X - relativePoint.X + 5);

        button.Content = relativePoint;
    }


private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.W)
        {
            moveUp(button1);
        }

        else if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            moveLeft(button1);
        }

        else if (e.Key == Key.S)
        {
            moveDown(button1);
        }

        else if (e.Key == Key.D)
        {
            moveRight(button1);
        }
    }
```

Please help or advise me how to go about solving this problem.

All help will greatly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi  Canvas.SetLeft(button, relativePoint.X - relativePoint.X + 5); This will always set the 'X co-ordinate to 5' , and Y co-ordinate will always be that of 'relativePoint' . So once it set for the first time then these same values will be set again and again. You need to change the logic of setting X coordinate valu in SetLeft method parameters.

Comment: hi ethicallogics, Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the logic was a bit out.

The correct way to do it is like this:

```
private void moveRight(Button button)
    {
        // Gets the current position of the control
        Point relativePoint = button.TransformToAncestor(parentCanvas).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        Canvas.SetLeft( button , 5 + relativePoint.X );
        button.Content = relativePoint;

     }
```

Its working now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Canvas.SetLeft(button, relativePoint.X - relativePoint.X + 5);
```

use

```
Canvas.SetLeft(button, relativePoint.X + 5);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: ive tried that already, it adds onto the previous x coordinate. For example coordinate is 100, on button press it jumps to 205 for some reason, thats why i tried the first way initially.

Comment: Hi , then problem is somewhere else because its working fine with me.